# How to use .predict() in a Linear Regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, predict

I'm trying to predict what a 15-minute delay in flight departure does to the flight's arrival time. I have thousands of rows as well as several columns in a DF. Two of these columns are dep_delay and arr_delay for departure delay and arrival delay. I have built a simple LinearRegression model:

```
y = nyc['dep_delay'].values.reshape((-1, 1))

arr_dep_model = LinearRegression().fit(y, nyc['arr_delay'])
```

And now I'm trying to find out the predicted arrival delay if the flights departure was delayed 15 minutes. How would I use the model above to predict what the arrival delay would be?

My first thought was to use a for loop / if statement, but then I came across `.predict()` and now I'm even more confused. Does .predict work like a boolean, where I would use "if departure delay is equal to 15, then arrival delay equals y"? Or is it something like:

```
arr_dep_model.predict(y)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `LinearRegression` models in sklearn you need to perform inference with the `predict()` function. But you also have to ensure the input you pass to the function has the correct shape *(the same as the training data)*. You can learn more about the proper use of predict function in the [official](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) documentation.

```
arr_dep_model.predict(youtInput)
```

This line of code would output a value that the model predicted for a corresponding input. You can insert this into a for loop and traverse a set of values to serve as the model's input, it depends on the needs for your project and the data you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check below code for an example:`

```html
import pandas as pd
import random 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':random.choices(range(0, 100), k=10), 'x2':random.choices(range(0, 100), k=10)})

df['y'] = df['x2'] * .5

X_train = df[['x1','x2']][:-3].values #Training on top 7 rows
y_train = df['y'][:-3].values #Training on top 7 rows

X_test = df[['x1','x2']][-3:].values # Values on which prediction will happen - bottom 3 rows

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

regr.predict(X_test)
```

If you will notice **X_test** the data on which prediction is happening is of same shape as (number of columns) as **X_train** both have two columns ['X1','X2']. Same has been converted in **array** when **.values** is used. You can create your own data (2 column dataframe for current example) & can use that for prediction (because 3rd column is need to be predicted).

Output will be three values as predicted on three rows:

[image]